Test/validation set
I've been having a discussion with colleagues and wanted to seek your input. If I'm using holdout and cross-validation to build and test my models. In this process, the training set is used to tune hyperparameters and evaluate the models. Then, a single model is selected from each candidate algorithm (e.g., ANN, SVM, etc. i.e. a final set of hyperparameters is chosen for each algo). Let's say I tried 10 different algorithms and ended up with 10 final models.
Is it acceptable to evaluate each of these final candidates on the test set? Or am I only allowed to assess a single final candidate on the test set? If so, assuming the single final candidate's performance on the training set isn't replicated on the test set, how should I proceed? I feel like as long as the test set is not exposed to the models, it should be valid for final model selection from the bunch. However, this might be similar to multiple testing in statistics.
Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Isn't the choice of the particular model (ANN vs SVM, say) a  hyperparameter to tune?

Does that mean that the training set alone is used to pick this hyperparameter or since it also involves a holdout, the test set may be used for this?
